# How to close collapse when I click outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a theme with Bootstrap 3 and I created a code to close the menu when I click outside.

In this menu, I have an `ui-autocomplete` field. The problem is that when I select a result in the `ui-autocomplete` list, the menu closes. I want it to stay open.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('.navbar-collapse *')) {
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.ui-autocomplete` class to avoid `collapse` on `click` too:

```
(function($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('.navbar-collapse *, .ui-autocomplete, .ui-autocomplete *')) {
      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    }
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

**Edit:** answer edited based on comments.

Comment: thanks, but your code does not work because "ui-autocomplete" is outside collapse. It would take my code and add an exception.

Comment: @Mathieu No problem so just add `ui-autocomplete` class to your selector. that's it

Comment: @Mathieu Should I type on address? nothing happend when I click and type on it

Comment: @Predam you must enter a city in the field to display the list

Comment: to type PARIS and wait 5 seconds, the list should appear

Comment: @Mathieu ok, now I got it, so you want when you click on result, avoid to close autocomplete or avoid to close navbar? I'm little confused

Comment: @Predam I do not want the collapse menu (navbar) to close.

Comment: I edited my answer, by looking at your website this is should work, this is my last suggest I think.